# Grouped Categories with DotNet.Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I try to build a grouped categories bar plot with DotNet.Highcharts similar to this example: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

I know how to set my own categories:

```
String[] myCategories = new String[] { "Category1", "Category2" };

DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
.SetXAxis(new XAxis
{
   Categories = myCategories
})
```

However I couldn't manage to initialize this chart with DotNet.Highcharts and subcategories which would require code similar to this example

```
        categories: [{
            name: "Fruit",
            categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
        }, {
            name: "Vegetable",
            categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
        }, {
            name: "Fish",
            categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
        }]
```

Any ideas how to get it done?

Thanks!

Comment: How about something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx ? Then use array of objects and arrays? Im not familair with asp.net but this link should be helpful

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was on that link before and tried it out. The problem is that 'Categories' of 'SetXAxis' takes an string array. I could only find rarely information about this issue. Here it says that DotNet does not support the case of grouped categories https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/435704 Nevertheless I still would be willing to get it work.

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this? I'm working on something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802637/dotnet-highcharts-cost-not-plotted-against-the-correct-date with no joy as of yet